# Using setInterval in Service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Please I want to use setInterval which shows a notification every 5 seconds  inside my service worker javascript file and it works fine at first but gradually after about 20 seconds it stops working

Here is the part where timer is initialized in the service worker java script file

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  setInterval(function()
   {

     self.registration.showNotification("title", {
       body: "test"
     });


   },5000);

});
```

Comment: Why are you creating a brand new `setInterval` every time your element is activated?  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am doing online task time manager so I want to run JavaScript timer in background even if browser itself is closed to show notification that specific task time ended

Comment: I don't think you can reliably do that in the client. You can send push notifications from the server instead though, which is probably better anyway.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

Service workers have a limited lifetime, you can't keep them alive forever.

See the [lifetime paragraph of the Service Workers specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-lifetime).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this case what is the alternative as I am doing online task time manager so I want to run JavaScript timer in background  even if browser itself is closed to show notification is specific task time ended

Comment: There's currently no alternative. In the future, maybe the Background Sync API (https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md).