# How to trigger offline background function when my PWA is closed

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Based on this answer:
[Using setInterval in Service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080706/using-setinterval-in-service-worker) from three years ago,

I would like to know if is there any way to make a PWA (via service worker or not) to trigger some background function time based and not network related.

I would like to push a notification using the navigator built in notification Chrome API every minute when my PWA is closed.

I see service workers main goals is to cache resources, but in every documentation I see that they are in some way "always active", so I feel one of those event listeners available should do what I am amaing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silently restarting your registered service worker **every minute** while your PWA is closed is something that browsers actively prevent. This would be a vector for malicious behavior in a lot of scenarios.

That being said, there are two options for starting up your registered service worker either not silently, or less frequently.

#### Push Notifications

On the "not silently" side of things, you could use [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications) to start up your service worker based on an incoming message sent from a push notification server. Users need to opt-in to receiving push notifications first. You're required to show a user-visible notification inside your service worker's `push` event handler, so this method isn't "silent."

You need to trigger these `push` events via a remote server. You can't "wake up" a service worker via `push` events coming from a local device.

#### Periodic Background Sync

[Periodic background sync](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/) is a newer feature that is closer to what you describe. It allows web apps that have met certain conditions to register for a `periodicsync` event that will be fired automatically (without requiring a remove server) on a recurring basis. You do not need to show a user-visible notification inside of this `periodicsync` event handler.

The specific limitations that apply to periodic background sync are browser-dependent, but at least in Chrome, you can't register for `periodicsync` events that are triggered anywhere nearly as frequently as once a minute. One event a day, if the other conditions are met, is about as often as you should expect.