# setInterval freezes react app after some time (couple days)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, setinterval

I have a react app (nextjs) and show a QR code that refreshes itself every 5 seconds and a clock which updates every 1 second.
Further, I have added service-worker to enable PWA and offline support.

After running it for a couple hours, or even days, out of nowhere the app freezes and does not update anymore.

If relevant, it happens on mobile devices (Android), maybe there is something up with energy saver mode or so?
Even if I pull down to refresh, the react app does not change! The only thing is exiting Chrome and then opening again.

I really have no clue what could be the cause of the issue.

RAM usage seems to be the same for all the time:

[image: RAM]

There are no network calls, everything is local, this is the example of the clock function that I use:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date());
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
```

The interval function that I use for the QR code is:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setOptions((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        data: generateQrCodeString(),
      }));
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

I use this qrcode lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-code-styling

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Appreciate any help!

#### Edit:

I tried the useInterval hook from here https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-interval and it seems to be working smoother, but after a couple hours/days, it still freezes.

Updated code:

```js
useInterval(() => {
    setTime(new Date());
  }, 1000);
```

```js
useInterval(() => {
    setOptions((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      data: generateQrCodeString(),
    }));
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

ServiceWorkers are specifically designed to be short-lived. The browser may terminate the service worker at any time.

Basically, you can't use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` reliably in a service worker. The supported way to keep a service worker alive is passing a promise to `waitUntil/respondWith`, but even then the browser may time out the promise and terminate the worker.

More about [waitUnitl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any recommendations of how to keep a page offline and use setInterval and setTimeout to show a clock / changing qr-code?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the pwa and check whether it still freezes or not. For me, it was cache-control headers with some caching values (for images), all I did was set cache-control to 0 and let pwa handle the caching by itself.

Comment: I agree with this comment. Also, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37082418/8122577

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remove the PWA/service worker, also disable caching, maybe also bypass Cloudflare too. Do you have an idea for offline support?

Comment: Offline support for what?

Comment: The service worker always listens to push messages, even when your pages aren't opened. So you can send data in push message, and based on that change the qr code. The only thing is service workers should be installed.

Comment: The business requirement is that the qr code refreshes itself every 5 seconds and the data for the code can be generated locally, no network call required. I added a service worker for offline support, as there is no internet connection required to generate the code, and so that the browser still shows the previously cached page after refresg.

Comment: Suppose there is no internet and PWA is installed, so the user will have to open the cached version of the application to see the QR ?? or there is a different approach?

Comment: The QR code can regenerate itself every 5 seconds without internet connection, the formula and keys are stored locally. With the PWA, a user could refresh the page and still get an up-to-date code.

Comment: So when user opens the app,  activate an (on load) event listener and do set interval on the event listener function. Now suppose 2 cases - 1st case: when there is no internet - the user will get a new QR code after every 5 seconds (due to the listener). 2nd case: the internet is available: if a new version(app update) is available, show a (notification/alert) button to hot reload the app (means stop auto-update). if no new version is available, do nothing. in all the cases QR will update after every 5 sec due to the event listener. And when the app is closed remove the event listener.

Answer (score -2):

So from your explanation what is happening is that you are caught in infinite loop with the setInterval method.

You can achieve what you wanted to do without react-hooks (useEffect or useInterval). Check the code below if it will help you.

```js
let seconds = 5;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  seconds = seconds - 1;
  console.log(seconds);
  if(seconds <=0){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```